# How to replace a label by backward filling

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, label, categories

I have the following dataset:

```html
index           Label           Value
0                NO              12
1                NO              13
2                NO              5
3                NO              8
4                NO              12
5                YES             10
6                YES             13
7                YES             9
8                YES             18
9                NO              12
10               NO              10
11               NO              7
```

My objective is to replace the last three labels of NO before the first YES Label to YES.

So, I would like to have the following data:

```html
index           Label           Value
0                NO              12
1                NO              13
2                YES             5
3                YES             8
4                YES             12
5                YES             10
6                YES             13
7                YES             9
8                YES             18
9                NO              12
10               NO              10
11               NO              7
```

So indices 2,3, and 4 turned into YES labels

Comment: Are there multiple streaks of YES, for which this needs to happen or only the first instance of YES?

Comment: There are multiple streaks of YES. I need this to happen like for every streak of YES. One more thing, is that the length of the streak varies. @ALollz

Answer (score 2):

#### `where` + `bffill`

```
df['Label'] = df.Label.where(df.Label.eq('YES')).bfill(limit=3).fillna(df.Label)

    index Label  Value
0       0    NO     12
1       1    NO     13
2       2   YES      5
3       3   YES      8
4       4   YES     12
5       5   YES     10
6       6   YES     13
7       7   YES      9
8       8   YES     18
9       9    NO     12
10     10    NO     10
11     11    NO      7
```